# Can't Link To MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am learning MySQL/PHP and I cannot figure out how to connect to MySQL on my localhost. I have written a short bit of code and I included root as my user name and root as my password because I have not set these elements yet (as far as I know). I feel that perhaps I am missing something in regards to the username/password combination. However, I feel that this should not be an issue because I have not tampered with the default conditions.

I need some help.

My code is below:

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shirts4max;port=3306", "root", "root");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to the database.";var_dump($e);
    exit;
}
```

I am only seeing the error message on my page:

"Could not connect to the database."

Thank for reading. Please help me Obiwan.

Comment: instead of `var_dump($e)` try `echo $e->getMessage()`

Comment: each of those statements can throw their own exception, you're just lumping them all under "couldn't connect". if you connect, but the exec() fails, then you STILL stay "couldn't connect", even if the problem really was a query syntax error or something.

Answer (score 2):

Show the **real** error. Avoid using `root` except for **maintenance**.

From the PDO Manual page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), modified for you

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=shirts4max;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting via command line using: `mysql -uroot -proot -hlocalhost -p3306`? If you can't connect that way, the PDO connection won't go through either. Playing with the connection info via command line gives you a nice easy way to find what works, then include it in your code. Also, if you've not set the user/pw, it's possible there isn't one currently, so you wouldn't need those parameters at all.